# FullCalendar + Google Service Account API

Tags: calendar, google-api, fullcalendar

Has anyone used [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) plus a Google Service Account API to get calendar events?

I've read that FullCalendar can consume a public calendar but I don't want to make my calendar public. So my plan is to have my web application use the service account api, so my application will fetch the protected data and then use FullCalendar to display the data.

So before I started all the work of getting this working I thought I'd ask if anyone has the code already. I've gotten the service account up and running, I'm just now looking into what it's going to take to get these two working together.

Comment: You didn't mention the language, but this project seems to be doing exactly this, with PHP fetching the calendar data: https://github.com/ori11238/ClusterCalendar

Comment: Hi Michael, did you find a way to use FullCalendar with Google Service Account API? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi Davidg, no i didn't. I started going through google's tutorials and if the calendar permission was set to public, then I could access the calendar through the API, if the calendar was private then the API couldn't access it. Life got busy and I haven't had time to figure out what I was doing wrong.